# Is this symbol the 'tensor product' or the 'outer product'?

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d, centroid

I need to compute the centroid of 3D polygons that are either triangles or quads, I found the following formula but I'm not sure about the meaning of the symbol in the last formula:

[Centroid of a 3D shell described by 3 vertex facets](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonmesh/)

[image]

Is this the tensor product, the outer product, or something else ?

Comment: I am pretty sure, that the cross product is meant.

Comment: Alright, going to give it a try and post my results.

Comment: You're right it's that ! However the formula I've posted is weird since when I get the center of a quad made out of 2 triangles, it is off-center. Good old averaging simply works the best. If you want to post an answer I'll mark it as such. Thanks.

Comment: I added it as you wanted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meant product is the cross product. No Problem :)